# logrotate compress only last n logs

Tags: logrotate

I need to make a daily rotate of /var/log/messages to be kept for 60 days, where the last 30 logs must be compressed with bzip2.

This is my logrotate config:

```
/var/log/messages {                                                                                              daily
    rotate 60
    postrotate
    /bin/kill -HUP `cat /var/run/syslogd.pid 2> /dev/null` 2> /dev/null || true    
    endscript 
}
```

but the result is keeping the last 60 daily not compressed logs. If add `compress`, then all 60 logs will be compressed.

So is there a way to make it compress ONLY the last 30 logs?

Answer (score 7):

I think there is no such option for logrotate to do it directly. Only one relevant option is `delaycompress` which delay the compression by one log rotate cycle (one day in your case). Possibly, you can make use of the `compresscmd` option by writing a shell script to check how many log files you have so far and compress/uncompress the files you want.

Another possibility is to schedule a daily `cron` job to run a script to check your log files and compress/uncompress what you want.

Comment: delaycompress is exactly what I looking for, useful to keep one rotated log as uncompressed to allow manipulations with already rotated log by a side parsers, etc.